Update cells with custom formula upon any part of workbook being edited
I have a custom formula where I check the workbook for a certain cell color and return the sum. I also want to update the cell for the last date and time the function was run/updated. I currently have two triggers set up to run the countColoredCells function and updateCellValue function.
The countColoredCells function is only triggered when I update anything in column A on any sheet. The updateCellValue is only updated when I update column A in the last sheet where I want to input the date and time in the specific cell.
Here is my code:
function countColoredCells(countRange, colorRef) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const formula = ss.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  let searchColor, countRangeA1;
  try {
    const colorRefA1 = formula.match(/\,(.+)\)/).pop().trim();
    searchColor = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(colorRefA1).getBackground();
    countRangeA1 = formula.match(/\((.+)\,/).pop().trim();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Bad arguments.');
  }
  let count = 0;
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
    count += sheet.getRange(countRangeA1).getBackgrounds()
      .flat()
      .filter(c => c === searchColor)
      .length
  });
  return count;
}

function updateCellValue() {
var date = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('G2').setValue(new Date().toLocaleString());
return date;
}

How can I simplify this and make sure the countColoredCells function and updatedCellValue is called every time the spreadsheet is edited (regardless of what they edit) or have it automatically update every 30 minutes?
I have tried various different triggers and for loops. No luck so far.

This question is similar to: App Script: How to update spreadsheet cell with live data. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
